# JqueryMobile use css3 target device

Tags: hash, css, jquery-mobile, target

i try to use :target css3 in a webapp with jQueryMobile but the hash in the href send event.

i try to put false on hash event but it's doesn't work.

Did you got ways or ideas ?

thx so !

i've go this type of menu :

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home"><img alt="Home" src="home.png"></a>
<li><a href="#apps"><img alt="Apps" src="apps.png"></a>
<li><a href="#pics"><img alt="Pics" src="pics.png"></a>
<li><a href="#chat"><img alt="Chat" src="chat.png"></a>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and this kind of section :

```
<section id="home">
<h1>Welcome :)</h1>
<p>
without highly efficient portals. Distinctively recaptiualize bricks and
clicks laboration and idea sharing through holistic business models.
</p>
</section>
[...]
```

this elements are on a single page and i try to use this css3 :target

```
#home:target {
margin-top:-1200px;
}
```

but jQueryMobile try to find the page #home

and my mobile init have got :

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'flip';
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
});
```

package are here : http://www.oxynel.com/jqm-css3-target.zip

sorry i've got images and i just discover exemple on jsfiddle !

Best

Fabian

Comment: We really need to see some code and a _lot_ more detail to this question. We can't help you blindfolded.

Comment: i edit my question hope with more information

Comment: Thx @JamWaffles just a way not a solution i love challenge !

Answer (score 0):

on your link try:

data-role="none"  JQM should leave the link alone.